# Google Analytics Metrics and Dimension Exclusion groups

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

There is a set of Google Analytics Dimension and Metrics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets some of them are incompatible between each other.

Need to get full list of what are the incompatible items. I.e. `ga:visitorType` excludes `ga:impressions`, `ga:adClicks`, `ga:adCost`...

I've been analyzing the page (url is few lines above), and found out a https://developers.google.com/apps/js/analytics_dm/analytics_dm_js-bundle.js with declaration of some "Cubes" at the end, but still can't get the explicit list of which dimensions and metrics exclude each other.

Can anybody share this list if any?

Comment: What do you mean by "incompatible items"? As far as I can tell, ga:visitorType is a dimension taking values such as "returning visitor" and "new visitor". What do you mean it excludes ga:impressions?

Comment: When I've had questions like this, the _best_ way that I've found so far to answer them has been to experiment with the [explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/ga_cubes.json

It was referenced in the [ga-dev-tools repository](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/master/lib/handlers/ga_cubes.py) and it contains a 9000+ line JSON object of all groupings of Google Analytics Metrics and Dimensions that are compatible for specific cubes.

As far as I know, this isn't publicly mentioned in Google's API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular list. For finding out the particular list possible combination click expand all check box on the page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=visitor 
Then when you hover over any particular dimension/metric a checkbox appears. Check it and see the items which are grayed out[those are the non allowed with that particular dimension /metrics]
This is how we do find out our required fields relatated info